# How do I print $rootScope variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This code is not working:

```
<td><img src="{{$rootScope.s3BucketUrl}}"/></td>
```

and this is where it's defined:

```
var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $resource, $location, $route, sharedProperties, $q, $rootScope){
    defer = $q.defer();
    //$rootScope.s3BucketUrl = 'http://lynd.s3.amazonaws.com/';//comment below one when live
    $rootScope.s3BucketUrl = 'http://lynd-test.s3.amazonaws.com/';
//code omitted
});
```

AppCtrl is bound first on body tag.

Could anybody please suggest how do I print $rootScope variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `{{s3BucketUrl}}` and you would get the value.

Your current scope is a child scope of rootscope and hence you can always access the elements of rootscope.

This [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) is highly recommended

Comment: How do I access `$rootScope`'s variable `x` if I have a variable named `x` in child scope too?

Comment: Inject $rootScope into the controller and directly acess it `$rootScope.x`